# Jenkins integration in Gitlab, "Jenkins url can't be blank"

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, integration, webhooks

When I try to link a jenkins project to my gitlab project, I have the following error :
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDREP.png) is the form and the error message.

The jenkins project "test" does exists and the credentials are good.
The issue is probably not about the credentials but that gitlab seem to not be able to read the fields.
I tried with both chrome and Firefox.

I also tried to use webhook, but for services hosted on the same network, [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/webhooks.html) says it may be hazardous. So I'd rather use the first method.

Some information about my environment:

```
Linux Centos 7
jenkins and gitlab are built by docker-compose
hosted on localhost
jenkins and gitlab use different ports (8080 and 8081)
```

I found only one thread on the internet about it [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/300121) but no answer were given.

Any ideas?
Thanks
This is my first post, I hope I did not make any mistake.\

Comment: This [page](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/300121) corresponds to the reporting of the bug to GitLab. This bug is still marked as "open" and therefore there is no fix yet. You have no choice but to wait for a workaround to be proposed or for the bug to be fixed and integrated in a new version of GitLab.